# Como retornar o valor de uma promise para fora do seu escopo

Tags: react, typescript, axios, callback

[Odeio javascript/typescript] É o seguinte, estou com um problema onde preciso pegar o resultado de uma promise com o axios e retornar em uma função no react. Existe alguma forma de fazer isso ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero retornar o valor na variavel resp.

Comment: Exporta a função e importa ela aonde vc quer usar

Answer (score 0):

Ficaria algo como:

```js
const suaFuncao = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get("url_sua_api");

  const { data } = response.data

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O axios trabalha com promisse, então você precisa esperar o promisse resolver em algum momento.

Testa esse código, dessa forma você resolve dentro da própria função:

```
static async findCursoPessoa(coddisciplina: string){
    try {
        coddisciplina = coddisciplina.replace('/', '-');
        const { data } = await Axios.get(`/pessoal/pessoa/${coddisciplina}/buscarCursos`);
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        return error; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const function= async()=> {
 const response = await axios.get("localhost");
 const {data} = response.data
 return data;
}
```